# Twisted Socket Ports and Classes

Tags: python, ios, sockets, twisted

I am working on a Blackjack iPhone app that interacts with a Twisted socket to allow online gameplay. My issue at the moment is finding the right port. Let me explain.

I created a class called "Table". It holds information like a Blackjack table, like positions, players, and the card deck. One table is assigned to one Twisted socket, and one socket is assigned to one port. Right now, I am testing only ports 1025-1034.

What I want to happen is the app requests to get the number of players at each table by going in order of ports ascending. For testing, I only allow 1 user at a table. If 1 user is at a table, I want the socket to return Table_Not_Found, but instead, even if a user is at a table, the socket returns the port a person is at and not the next port that has nobody.

I don't think I am doing something right with the Table class and searching for an open table. How can I find the right port? The app connects to a port, if the port is taken, then it returns Table_Not_Found, then the app requests the next port available. But in my case, the socket always returns the port taken. I can only test with my iMac and MacBook as they are the clients.

Bottom line, how do I search for an available table on port?

Thanks!

```
class Table:
    def __init__(self):
        self.players = []
        self.positions = []
        self.id = 0
        self.numberOfPlayers = 0

    def setID(self, _id):
        self.id = _id

    def setActivePlayer(self, player):
        player.countdown = 20
        while player.count > 0:
            print player.countdown
            time.sleep(1)
            player.countdown -= 1

            if player.countdown == 0:
                print "Out of time"

                moves.surrender(player)


class Socket(Protocol):
    table = Table()

    def connectionMade(self):
        #self.transport.write("""connected""")
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "Clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        #print "data is ", data
        a = data.split(':')
        if len(a) > 1:
            command = a[0]
            content = a[1]

            b = content.split(';')
            _UDID = b[0].replace('\n', '')

            if command == "Number_of_Players":
                if Socket.table.numberOfPlayers == 0:
                    msg = "%s:TableFound" % _UDID
                elif Socket.table.numberOfPlayers == 1:
                    msg = "%s:Table_Not_Found" % _UDID

        print msg

        for c in self.factory.clients:
                c.message(msg)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message)

NUM_TABLES = 10

factories = [ ]
for i in range(0, NUM_TABLES):
    print i
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = Socket
    factory.clients = []
    factories.append(factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(1025+i, factory)
    #print "Blackjack server started"

reactor.run()
```

Comment: Why do you think you need different ports for this? If all the ports are to provide the same functionality, you don't need that. You can have as many as you want connections, to only one port.

Comment: Second, (anyone correct me if I am wrong), in the current code, the `table` is a class variable, so you have only one Table, accessible by all sockets, not one per port.

Comment: If you want one table per Socket, I think it's better to define `table` inside the `Socket.__init__()` method.

Comment: But I really do think that it's better to have just one Protocol and one port. You'll probably need some structures to hold the list of available Tables, Users connected, the table they are playing, etc. These could be in a central object (say BlackJackServer).

Comment: Then maybe if I had no table and put all the table stuff inside the socket, it could work? This is so tough for me, I'm really strong in the iPhone side, but this python stuff is tough. :(

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you're having is the `table = Table()` in your socket class.  This means that for all `Socket` instances ever, there is only one `Table`.

The quick fix is to store each `Table` on a `Factory` so that all connections to that `Factory` (i.e. that listening TCP port) will share a single `Table` instance.

This can be accomplished by removing `table = Table()` line, and then modifying your `for` loop like so:

```
for i in range(0, NUM_TABLES):
    print i
    factory = Factory()
    factory.table = Table() # <-- add this line
    factory.protocol = Socket
    factory.clients = []
    factories.append(factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(1025+i, factory)
```

And then adjusting your `connectionMade` to start like this:

```
def connectionMade(self):
    self.table = self.factory.table
```

Now each `Socket` is pointing at its `Factory`'s `Table`.

However, there are a number of other serious problems with this code:

- You don't need, and shouldn't use, multiple ports for this protocol.  Each new connection should show up and identify what blackjack game it wants to play in with a message over the protocol itself.  Working over multiple ports just makes it harder for people to get through firewalls to play your game.  You can use the same strategy, just setting the `table` attribute on the appropriate `Socket` instance.
- You are expecting `dataReceived` to be called with whole messages.  [It won't be, and this is a FAQ that you should read in the Twisted docs.](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Whyisprotocol.dataReceivedcalledwithonlypartofthedataIcalledtransport.writewith)  Or rather, it will be when you are testing, but then not when you deploy to the real internet.  If you're doing iPhone development, you should use Network Link Conditioner to simulate real internet connections.
- Since you don't seem to know how network protocol parsing works, you should use [a protocol construction kit like `AMP`](http://amp-protocol.net/) to build up your wire protocol.  [The API documentation includes a brief tutorial.](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.amp.html)
- You're calling `time.sleep`.  That will block the whole server.  This is the wrong way to build a time-sensitive Twisted service.  More importantly, Twisted won't process input while it's blocked waiting for your `time.sleep` to complete, so every player will always instantly surrender rather than being able to play any cards.  You should use [`callLater`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTime.html#callLater) instead, to schedule timed calls that change the state of the game.

*Most* of the problems you're having though are object-composition problems, and not things that are super specific to Twisted or to Python.  You need to draw out a map for yourself of what instances should be pointing at what other things.  The important thing to understand is that when you make a call into the reactor like `listenTCP` or `callLater`, what you are setting up is a reference from the reactor to your object.  There's nothing magic about it; you're just saying "later, call this method, on this object, under these circumstances".  Everything flows out from there; your sockets having references to your tables, your tables having references to their players, and so on.

Comment: Glyph, that was an awesome answer! You gave me the problems with the code, etc. The only problem is that I can't access the code until the weekend when I head back to that computer. I'll make all the adjustments this weekend. My question is why not use ports? It seems fine, but I guess it's not.

Comment: @AlecK.: Imagine you want a user to change from one table to another. With your design, he'll have to disconnect and connect again to another port, and this (possibly) means lower level checks for credentials, firewalls pass and all other things that have to de done for a connection to be established. And what if during that time, the new table's seats have been capturedby other players? You have driven a player off the Server.

Comment: The server will auto join the table. I have written myself an iPhone library that makes the server connecting easy. The tables are unlimited limits, no reason for a user to change tables. The final product would not be my computer, I will invest in other hardware.